# How do you access a template from inside a Symfony Bundle that is located in "<BundleLocation>/Ressources/views"?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating an application for a Symfony web project that I have made previously as a portable bundle. I've created a "media.html.twig" template and want it to be called by the render() helperfunction.

I've activated the bundle in /config/bundles.php with

```php
App\OM\MediaManagerBundle\OMMediaManagerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

and followed the instructions on this site https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html for setting up the Symfony-Bundle folder structure and the required files.
I've prefixed the path with "@MediaManager" as told by this site https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/best_practices.html#resources.

This is my Controller class:

```php
<?php


namespace App\OM\MediaManagerBundle\Controller;


use App\OM\MediaManagerBundle\Form\ImageType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MediaManagerController extends AbstractController
{
    const TEMPLATE = "@MediaManager/MediaManager/media.html.twig";

    /**
     * @Route("/media/", name="om_mediamanager_media")
     * */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ImageType::class);

        return $this->render(self::TEMPLATE,
            [
               'form'   =>  $form->createView(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

This is how my folder structure looks like inside src:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji3Gu.png

I hoped my form would be displayed but instead I got an error message saying:

```
There are no registered paths for namespace "MediaManager".
```

I know that it starts looking from the /templates folder so I tried setting the path to "../src/OM/MediaManagerBundle/Resources/views/MediaManager/media.html.twig" but got

```
Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (../src/OM/MediaManagerBundle/Resources/views/MediaManager/media.html.twig).
```

The code does work when I move the "media.html.twig" template inside the /templates folder but I expect it to ruin the portability of the bundle and therefor don't want to do that.

How do I access this template from inside my OMMediaManagerController class?
Am I even using Symfony Bundles the right way?
Is there any more documentation about Bundles in general? I found the ones provided by the official site to be very lacking.

Comment: Start by running "bin/console debug:twig" and looking at the namespace section.  Your post has several inconsistencies which could just be copy/paste errors or the actual source of the problem.  And "@MediaManager/media.html.twig" is what your want to end up with.

Comment: I've tried running debug:twig yesterday and it showed me no namespace for my bundle but today I ran it again after reading your comment and there was @OMMediaManager added for some reason. I change the path to "@OMMediaManager/MediaManager/media.html.twig" and renamed my folder in views from "mediamanager" to "MediaManager" and now the template is loading as expected. I still have no idea why it's suddenly recognizing the namespace and what went wrong yesterday but my problem is solved now.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with my IDE (IntelliJ Ultimate) because I unmarked my /src folder as "Source Root" yesterday in order to create directories in the GUI and today it has been remarked automatically.